# How to update the mini-cart proceed to checkout according to customer login in magento 2?

Tags: checkout, customer, url, mini-cart, magento2.3.0

I Want to check the user login status in mini cart and redirect the customer to the login page when click the proceed to checkout button in mini-cart.

How to edit the **minicart.js** file to achieve this?

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view

```
'url': {
            'checkout': window.checkout.checkoutUrl,
            'update': window.checkout.updateItemQtyUrl,
            'remove': window.checkout.removeItemUrl,
            'loginUrl': window.checkout.customerLoginUrl,
            'isRedirectRequired': window.checkout.isRedirectRequired
        },
```

How to use the if condition to check the user is logged or not logged?
[image]

I want to forcefully redirect to the customer (registered or guest) to the login page and after logged mini cart proceeds to checkout, the button should redirect to the checkout page.

**Update**

I did following changes to **minicart.js**

```
define([
'uiComponent',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',//Added this line
'jquery',
'ko',
'underscore',
'sidebar',
'mage/translate',
'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData, customer, $, ko, _) { //Passed argument customer
'use strict';

//checked the customer logged or not.
if(customer.isLoggedIn()){
        alert("yes");
        var urls = window.checkout.checkoutUrl;
    }else{
        alert("no");
        var urls = window.checkout.customerLoginUrl;
    }

esidebarInitialized = true;
    miniCart.sidebar({
        'targetElement': 'div.block.block-minicart',
        'url': {
            'checkout': urls,
            'update': window.checkout.updateItemQtyUrl,
            'remove': window.checkout.removeItemUrl,
            'loginUrl': window.checkout.customerLoginUrl,
            'isRedirectRequired': window.checkout.isRedirectRequired
        }, 
................... rest of the code of the file
```

Unfortunately **customer.isLoggedIn()** this return always not logged.
How to check a customer is logged or not logged?

Answer (score 0):

There is two option

1. Allow Guest Checkout is No

Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Option

Allow Guest Checkout = No

Otherwise customise to sidebar.js

vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\sidebar.js

line no 63

```
 events['click ' + this.options.button.checkout] = $.proxy(function () {
            var cart = customerData.get('cart'),
                customer = customerData.get('customer'),
                element = $(this.options.button.checkout);

            if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false) {
                // set URL for redirect on successful login/registration. It's postprocessed on backend.
                $.cookie('login_redirect', this.options.url.checkout);

                if (this.options.url.isRedirectRequired) {
                    element.prop('disabled', true);
                    location.href = this.options.url.loginUrl;
                } else {
                    authenticationPopup.showModal();
                }

                return false;
            }
            element.prop('disabled', true);
            location.href = this.options.url.checkout;
        }, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code needs a little change.

to get a customer login status try this code:

```
if(customerData.get('customer').firstname){
    console.log("customerData",true);
    var urls = window.checkout.checkoutUrl; 
}else{
    console.log("customerData",false);
    var urls = window.checkout.customerLoginUrl;
}
```

this will return true if customer is loggedin otherwise false.